# Exporting Multilayered DEM Maps from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, wms, geotiff-tiff, dem, export

I'm currently working on a project in ArcGIS Pro where I've created a map featuring multilayered Digital Elevation Models (DEMs) with various blend modes applied. My goal is to export this map for printing on an A4 page. To achieve this, I set up a Layout in ArcGIS Pro tailored to my needs.

However, I'm facing a significant issue. When I export this layout as a GeoTIFF, the resulting file doesn't closely resemble what I see within the ArcGIS Pro interface. This discrepancy isn't limited to GeoTIFFs alone; I'm experiencing the same problem with PDF and JPG formats. The colors, blending, and details that are crisp and clear in the ArcGIS Pro layout appear markedly different in the exported files.

[image]

Screenshot of what I'm seeing in ArcGIS.

[image]

My settings.

[image]

Exported TIFF.

Comment: When I opened ArcGIS today in an attempt to fix the problem I saw multiple exclamation marks next to my generated layers. After I redid them using Slope, Hillshade and Statistical Functions it worked and I got my intended TIFF. However Im still wondering why they somehow didn't load.